# How to bind a style to an element outside of the component using HostBinding

Tags: angular

I'd like to add `overflow:hidden/visible` to the body tag depending on whether a modal is visible or not. I'd like to achieve this with `@HostBinding` if possible but I don't know how.

Something like this is what I want:

```
constructor(private _modalApi: ModalApiService) {

  _modalApi.isOpen$.subscribe(
    modal => {
      this.overflow = this.isOpen ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
    }
  )
}

@HostBinding('body.style.overflow')
overflow: string;
```

I realise that `@HostBinding` binds to the host element which in this case would be the modal, but since `@HostListener` can listen to the document, window etc I thought that there might be a similar use case here.

Is this possible or do I have to make some weird workaround?

Note that I've looked at other questions suggesting to put your app component on the body tag and then doing it via the app component, however, I can't rely on another component since the idea is that this component shouldn't know about any app's structure and still work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported. As `HostBinding` indicates it binds to the host element of the component, not some arbitrary element.

The `document:xxx`, `window:xxx`, or `body:xxx` targets of the `HostListener` decorator is special.

You can use plain DOM access as a workaround or some other way to get an `ElementRef` and use the `Renderer` to apply styles or other settings.

Comment: Then how would you go about doing this?

Comment: Isn't "plain DOM access" bad though?

Comment: That's right, it should be avoided. If you use any non-Angular2 JS libraries you're implicitly doing direct DOM access anyway. Then trying to avoid it in your own code is a bit pointless anyway. If you want to stick with the "correct" Angular2 approach you can use `ElementRef` and `Renderer`. How you can get an `ElementRef` of the target element depends on your app structor. It's hard to make suggestions with the available information.

Comment: Looks like this will be a trickier thing to solve than I expected, thanks for the help anyways.